# Spring Boot in AKS using CosmosDB

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, azure-aks

I have a spring boot in an aks pod. I have set up a Cosmos DB repository.

When the pod is starting and initializes the CosmosDB connection, the pod crashes, keeping in a CrashLoopBackOff Status.

Please, Do you have any idea what the reason is?

Comment: I think you need to provide more details sir. Have you tried to do [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting#my-pod-is-stuck-in-crashloopbackoff-mode-what-should-i-do)? Many points may lead to CrashLoopBackOff, and what we can get from your question is the only CrashLoopBackOff.

Comment: Yes, I know that the pod crashs when the cosmosdb initialization starts.

Comment: can you provide the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally It was an issue with the container resource limits ( 500mb ). Increasing that value it was more than enough to solve the issue.